# "x and y are what drive them" vs "x and y are what driveS them"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, what

Which of the following is correct?

> It seems evident that self-confidence and a desire for power are what **drive**
>   them to enter this competition.
>
> It seems evident that self-confidence and a desire for power are what **drives**
>   them to enter this competition.

Comment: are what -> drive; is what -> drives

Comment: I just replaced the generic formulation with the actual sentence in the question above. Sorry if this simplification actually made the question harder to answer.

Comment: And don't forget the possibility of *"It seems evident that self-confidence and a desire for power **is** what **drives** them to enter this competition."* :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual usage stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php) look as follows:

```
                  COCA    BNC

are what drive      10      0
are what drives      3      1
are what have       11      2
are what has         6      0
are what make       97      6
are what makes      25      3
are what tell        2      0
are what tells       0      0
```

So as you can see, American English rather clearly leans the plural way, while British English is either undecided, or the corpus size is simply too small to say anything definitely.

Personally, I do have to point out that the COCA results are actually at odds with the dialect I speak, where the variant with "what drive" strikes me as ungrammatical. (The antedecent of *what* might be plural, but the *what* itself is singular. All you need to do is to look at the *what* clause, an embedded question. And "*what drive them to do Z" is not a grammatical question in my dialect, or indeed for all I can tell in any variety of English. The question is, "what *drives* them to do it", and you are providing the answer to that. The "are" is a red herring, because it agrees with "X and Y" and is not part of the *what* clause at all.)

However, this kind of discrepancy between different dialects is nothing unusual, and there is even a name for this particular phenomenon: [notional agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis). (For example, that's also the reason why we say "a lot of people are", even though "a lot" is clearly singular.)

Comment: If they're ungrammatical, a [lot of people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+what+has%2C+are+what+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20what%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20what%20have%3B%2Cc0) speak ungrammatically. (Actually, this Ngram gives a lot of false posities, but they also return a lot of real results both ways.)

Comment: @Peter yes, I am compiling stats myself as we speak. Hold on.

Comment: "Are what make(s)" is a good test case to look at: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+what+makes%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Care+what+makes%3Aeng_us_2012%2Care+what+make%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Care+what+make%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20what%20makes%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20what%20makes%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20what%20make%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20what%20make%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) seems to say that the plural construction is the traditional way to do it (in both the UK and US).

Comment: And of course, if you turn the sentence around, I assume that the only grammatical construction (for any standard dialect) is: *"It seems evident that what drives them to enter this competition is self-confidence and a desire for power"*.

Comment: What is the plural of "what" (as a pronoun) in your dialect?

Comment: @JdeBP: the plural of *what* is *what*, but I am not sure how that is relevant here. I am not saying that *what* can't be plural at all, just that it happens to be singular in this particular case. When you say "I have a sheep", clearly *sheep* is singular; that in other contexts it can easily be plural has no bearing on the context at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the deck is a bit stacked in the way you ask the question. You offer

> X and Y **are** what drive them to do Z
>
> X and Y **are** what drives them to do Z

In both examples, you have treated *X and Y* as a plural concept, as indicated by the use of *are* instead of *is*. In that case, *what* is logically plural and should take **drive**, the third person plural form.

However, there may be circumstances in which you want *X and Y* to be seen as a collective, a single driving force. In that case you could use a single verb form throughout

> Fish and chips is what drives them into the restaurant.

But where the forces are independent (either alone might drive the actors), you should preserve the plural throughout

> Both dedication and monetary gain are what drive people into the field of medicine.

**SUPPLEMENT**

The above answer was crafted before the illustrative sentences were added, but the logic is the same.  It still is not clear as to whether *both* characteristics must be present for the result or either one alone might drive the result.

> It seems evident that self-confidence and a desire for power are *things that can* drive them to enter this competition.
>
> but
>
> It seems evident that *the concurrence of* self-confidence and a desire for power is what drives them to enter this competition.

Answer (score -1):

It depends whether the sense is of a singular or plural subject.

For instance, 'The Brothers Karamazov drives me to drink.'

Or 'The Montgolfier brothers invented the hot air balloon.'

Where this is ambiguity in a phrase, eg 'The Canterbury Tales', the choice of verb should accord with the term intended.